# Simplify a radical inside a radical inside a radical

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

The question is this:

Simplify $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{21+12\sqrt{3}}}$

I defined the value as x, then got $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2$=$21+12\sqrt{13}$.

I don't know what to do from there. Any help?

Comment: I think you mean the equation to be $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2=\color{red}{211}+12\sqrt{13}$ instead of $(x+1)^2(x-1)^2=\color{red}{21}+12\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: @AidenChow No, I meant for the radical 21 not radical 211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$21+12 \sqrt{3} = (3+2\sqrt{3})^2$$

and
$$4 + 2 \sqrt{3} = (1 + \sqrt{3})^2$$

Comment: Not a hint, but an answer....

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Not really, I did not write the step where you have to see that $3+1=4$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe thanks, but yeah you could've left it at 3+ 2..., since the last step is obvious